# How to clear page previous state when clicking on tab control buttons Ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have application that has tab control with few buttons on the bottom and classical navigation control with page content above it. When I select some one of the tabs, page content changes. I have navigation to other pages from that page and etc. I make some selection, navigate to some page and then go and change tab. Page content is then refresh as it suppose to be. But if I go back to first page, my previous selection still stays there. I would like to clear navigation page to it's initial state once the user left that page and clicked other tab.
Does anybody know a way to accomplish this by using Ionic and AngularJs?
Is there some event that can be triggered for this? I know that most of the mobile applications have this kind of a behavior where navigation page is returned to initial state once user clicked on the other tab.

I've tried to do this by using openTabAndRefresh event:

```
 openTabAndRefresh(index) {
    // this.navController.popToRoot().then(() => {
    //   this.tabRefs.goToRoot();
    //   this.navController.parent.popToRoot();
    //   this.navController.setRoot(this.tabRefs[index].root);
    // this.tabRefs.select(index);
    //});
    this.tabRefs.select(index);
  }

  openHome() {
        this.openTabAndRefresh(0);
    }

  openNewOrder() {
    this.openTabAndRefresh(14);
    }

    openMyOrder() {
    this.openTabAndRefresh(2);
    }

    openMyProfile () {
    this.openTabAndRefresh(3);
    }

  openOrders() {
    this.openTabAndRefresh(5);
  }
```

But I am not sure how to actually return page to initial state or can this event even help me with this. Does anybody has experience with this?

Comment: Hmm have you tried to reset your page in a [lifecycle event](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events) like `ionViewDidLeave`?

Comment: @Phonolog thanks for answering, I've just found something on that so I will try to use that life cycle event.